# How do I remove active clients from a stream?

Tags: stream, perforce

So I'm trying to remove a stream in perforce that I created in error. When I try to delete it, I get

```
Stream '//MyDepo/StreamIWantToDelete' has active clients; cannot delete until they are removed.
```

Which is fine, I can see myself when I:

```
p4 clients -a -S //MyDepo/StreamIWantToDelete
```

I do not know the appropriate command to remove myself from this stream so that I can delete it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Either delete the client (`p4 client -d`) or switch it to a different stream (`p4 switch`).